# Stream analytics job not reading data from ADLS2

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have created input using ADLS Gen2 data stream option. I have added path pattern (up to folder which gets continuous data from eventhub). Test connection is successful but when I try to run query or sample data, it fails and error is:

> Diagnostics: While sampling data, no data was received from '1' partitions.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Hi there, could you please share your path pattern, and the rest of the input configuration, so we can understand what could be going wrong?

Comment: Please also note that if the same data is accessible from an event hub, you should absolutely prefer reading it with the event hub input adapter instead. The ADLS stream input was designed to re-process historical data, it's not as performant for real streaming scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Florian, yes I ended up reading directly from Event hub which is more efficient so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Florian Eiden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633925/florian-eiden) and [Swati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4423300/swati) for your valuable discussions and suggestions. Posting it as answer to help other community members.

> Used Event Hub directly as data streaming input instead of ADLS Gen2
> data streaming option (that gets continuous data from Event Hub). This is more efficient option.

Comment: Hey @Swati, do let me know if the provided information solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot share you more details.